# Blender's compositor di-initializing time

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

Why does the di-initialization process for a cycles render take as  much time as the render itself. I have a scene composited with a single glow object. It takes 31 sec to render the frame with the glow and 27 sec to de-initialize the compositor? Am I missing a setting?